# Android AVD Manager change density

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I've installed the new android sdk, my question is how to change the density (for example 265)?

[image: screenshot1]

In density menu there isn't a custom value.

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html. http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html. Check the developer site links

Comment: ok but I don't have found how to change the density